# Change active state on fixed page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed page navigation that I am having trouble getting to respond on scroll. Below is an example of what my code looks like. As you can see, I am trying to get my page navigation (.service-nav) to respond to reach corresponding article id. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here's a snippet:**

```js
$('.service-con').scroll(function() {
  $('article').each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < 60) {
      $('.service-nav li').removeClass('active');
      $('.service-nav li.' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.service-nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
.service-nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.service-nav li a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.service-nav li.active a {
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.container {
  padding: 60px 20px 20px;
```

```html
<div id="parallax-page" class="service-con content-panel">
  <div class="service-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="380" data-offset-top="380">
    <ul>
      <li class="article1 active">
        <a href="#article1">
          <span class="tooltip">Article 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="article2">
        <a href="#article2">
          <span class="tooltip">Article 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <article id="article1">
      <h2>An Article</h2>
      <p>Nam faucibus tristique efficitur. Maecenas vitae justo at ante pulvinar rhoncus. Suspendisse tincidunt, justo eget ornare rutrum, tellus turpis pharetra dui, a lobortis ligula felis tempus nulla. Duis justo orci, convallis quis sem a, dapibus congue
        erat. Morbi ut tortor nisl. Duis porttitor euismod purus at sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent hendrerit ex ut tristique placerat. Proin congue fringilla leo, sit amet placerat est iaculis quis. Aliquam eu augue sed mi hendrerit dignissim. Sed nibh arcu, rutrum vel tempus vel,
        commodo a dolor. Fusce sed commodo nulla, et aliquet sem. Morbi posuere tincidunt dictum. Cras et commodo lectus, porta ornare enim.</p>
      <p>Curabitur vitae elementum mi, eu tempus neque. Quisque vulputate, lorem at mattis finibus, ante leo lacinia ex, vel tincidunt mi metus vitae enim. Mauris aliquam suscipit ipsum, tincidunt accumsan est eleifend a. Nunc ac libero nec nulla luctus
        pretium. Integer varius magna magna, in feugiat massa feugiat vel. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse vitae euismod mi. Suspendisse efficitur nisi augue, efficitur tempor nunc malesuada in. Fusce a nulla
        ut magna viverra porttitor. Morbi et enim quam. Quisque ornare, enim quis malesuada laoreet, sapien tellus aliquet metus, sed gravida ex lacus at leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla
        non leo at tortor hendrerit laoreet.</p>
    </article>

    <article id="article2">
      <h2>Another Article</h2>
      <p>Fusce rhoncus hendrerit lectus, nec aliquam lorem feugiat ac. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lacinia condimentum lacus quis tempor. In eget sem turpis. Maecenas nec accumsan leo.
        Cras tincidunt orci sed ligula suscipit egestas. Phasellus et semper quam. Sed metus erat, consectetur at ex et, auctor iaculis nibh. Sed hendrerit dolor in nunc tincidunt, quis vulputate diam pharetra. Aliquam ac ligula diam. Nulla aliquam, mi
        ut tristique ultricies, lacus leo dictum erat, nec fringilla metus augue quis lacus. Vestibulum semper euismod placerat. Nulla mattis lacus eget lacinia aliquet. Praesent massa ipsum, auctor eget nisl quis, accumsan eleifend elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent hendrerit ex ut tristique placerat. Proin congue fringilla leo, sit amet placerat est iaculis quis. Aliquam eu augue sed mi hendrerit dignissim. Sed nibh arcu, rutrum vel tempus vel,
        commodo a dolor. Fusce sed commodo nulla, et aliquet sem. Morbi posuere tincidunt dictum. Cras et commodo lectus, porta ornare enim.</p>
      <p>Curabitur vitae elementum mi, eu tempus neque. Quisque vulputate, lorem at mattis finibus, ante leo lacinia ex, vel tincidunt mi metus vitae enim. Mauris aliquam suscipit ipsum, tincidunt accumsan est eleifend a. Nunc ac libero nec nulla luctus
        pretium. Integer varius magna magna, in feugiat massa feugiat vel. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse vitae euismod mi. Suspendisse efficitur nisi augue, efficitur tempor nunc malesuada in. Fusce a nulla
        ut magna viverra porttitor. Morbi et enim quam. Quisque ornare, enim quis malesuada laoreet, sapien tellus aliquet metus, sed gravida ex lacus at leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla
        non leo at tortor hendrerit laoreet.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 $('article').each(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top-$(this).find('h2').height()-$('.service-nav').height()){
   $('.service-nav li').removeClass('active');
   $('.service-nav li.' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('active');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.service-nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
.service-nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.service-nav li a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
  .service-nav li.active a {
    border-color: #ccc;
  }

.container {
  padding: 60px 20px 20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parallax-page" class="service-con content-panel">
 <div class="service-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="380" data-offset-top="380">
  <ul>
   <li class="article1 active">
    <a href="#article1">
     <span class="tooltip">Article 1</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="article2">
    <a href="#article2">
     <span class="tooltip">Article 2</span>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <article id="article1">
   <h2>An Article</h2>
   <p>Nam faucibus tristique efficitur. Maecenas vitae justo at ante pulvinar rhoncus. Suspendisse tincidunt, justo eget ornare rutrum, tellus turpis pharetra dui, a lobortis ligula felis tempus nulla. Duis justo orci, convallis quis sem a, dapibus congue erat. Morbi ut tortor nisl. Duis porttitor euismod purus at sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent hendrerit ex ut tristique placerat. Proin congue fringilla leo, sit amet placerat est iaculis quis. Aliquam eu augue sed mi hendrerit dignissim. Sed nibh arcu, rutrum vel tempus vel, commodo a dolor. Fusce sed commodo nulla, et aliquet sem. Morbi posuere tincidunt dictum. Cras et commodo lectus, porta ornare enim.</p>
            <p>Curabitur vitae elementum mi, eu tempus neque. Quisque vulputate, lorem at mattis finibus, ante leo lacinia ex, vel tincidunt mi metus vitae enim. Mauris aliquam suscipit ipsum, tincidunt accumsan est eleifend a. Nunc ac libero nec nulla luctus pretium. Integer varius magna magna, in feugiat massa feugiat vel. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse vitae euismod mi. Suspendisse efficitur nisi augue, efficitur tempor nunc malesuada in. Fusce a nulla ut magna viverra porttitor. Morbi et enim quam. Quisque ornare, enim quis malesuada laoreet, sapien tellus aliquet metus, sed gravida ex lacus at leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla non leo at tortor hendrerit laoreet.</p>
  </article>

  <article id="article2">
   <h2>Another Article</h2>
   <p>Fusce rhoncus hendrerit lectus, nec aliquam lorem feugiat ac. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lacinia condimentum lacus quis tempor. In eget sem turpis. Maecenas nec accumsan leo. Cras tincidunt orci sed ligula suscipit egestas. Phasellus et semper quam. Sed metus erat, consectetur at ex et, auctor iaculis nibh. Sed hendrerit dolor in nunc tincidunt, quis vulputate diam pharetra. Aliquam ac ligula diam. Nulla aliquam, mi ut tristique ultricies, lacus leo dictum erat, nec fringilla metus augue quis lacus. Vestibulum semper euismod placerat. Nulla mattis lacus eget lacinia aliquet. Praesent massa ipsum, auctor eget nisl quis, accumsan eleifend elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent hendrerit ex ut tristique placerat. Proin congue fringilla leo, sit amet placerat est iaculis quis. Aliquam eu augue sed mi hendrerit dignissim. Sed nibh arcu, rutrum vel tempus vel, commodo a dolor. Fusce sed commodo nulla, et aliquet sem. Morbi posuere tincidunt dictum. Cras et commodo lectus, porta ornare enim.</p>
            <p>Curabitur vitae elementum mi, eu tempus neque. Quisque vulputate, lorem at mattis finibus, ante leo lacinia ex, vel tincidunt mi metus vitae enim. Mauris aliquam suscipit ipsum, tincidunt accumsan est eleifend a. Nunc ac libero nec nulla luctus pretium. Integer varius magna magna, in feugiat massa feugiat vel. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse vitae euismod mi. Suspendisse efficitur nisi augue, efficitur tempor nunc malesuada in. Fusce a nulla ut magna viverra porttitor. Morbi et enim quam. Quisque ornare, enim quis malesuada laoreet, sapien tellus aliquet metus, sed gravida ex lacus at leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla non leo at tortor hendrerit laoreet.</p>
  </article>
 </div>
</div>
```